WHM Ubuntu 22.04.4 didn't want to open PHP file
Hi guys im using a VPS and WHM to do a config, im already install the PHP using easyApache4 but why it won't open the php file? PHP-FPM is already activated but it still cant be accessed, its my first time so i was really getting confused. Also while accessing the terminal i cant find apache2, there's only httpd is there any solution for all of this?
i was just stuck for a day since yesterday, Helpp :')
Really need help to make the PHP file can be readable, like only do read the
<?
phpinfo()
?>

nothing else only that :(

"it won't open the php file" - what does that mean, exactly?  What happens when you visit your PHP file in a browser?  "make the PHP file can be readable" - are you seeing an error that suggests the file is not readable?  Edit your question, and explicitly describe the problem - what happens when you visit a PHP page, copy-paste the text of any error messges you see, etc.  BTW there is a syntax error in the code you've shown, there's a semi-colon ; missing.

Try using <?php instead of <?

@brombeer the vps was running really so well, and now it solved, i dont really know if the others developer was using the same domain in another hosting :D Thanks everyone
